# Create key-value pairs in JSON

Tags: json

I'm new to JSON. I'm trying to create a JSON object in Java (org.json.JSONObject(json.jar)) which resembles like (basically a set of name-value pairs)

[{
    "name": "cases",
    "value": 23
}, {
    "name": "revenue",
    "value": 34
}, {
    "name": "1D5",
    "value": 56
}, {
    "name": "diag",
    "value": 14
}]

Can anyone help me on how to create this in Java? I want the name and value to be in each so that i can iterate over the collection and then get individual values.

Comment: Do you mean a JSON *string*?

Comment: @ExplosionPills — I suspect he means a JSON text where the outermost data type is an object.

Comment: *I'm trying to create a JSON object in Java* — So which library are you using? (There are a number listed on the [JSON homepage](http://json.org/)). What code have you written to try to achieve this?

Comment: That isn't valid JSON. Sequential arrays are `[]`. Objects containing key/value pairs are `{}`. You have them backwards. You also seem to be using `=` instead of `:` in half the places.

Answer (score 3):

The valid json you're looking for is:

```
[{
    "name": "cases",
    "value": 23
}, {
    "name": "revenue",
    "value": 34
}, {
    "name": "1D5",
    "value": 56
}, {
    "name": "diag",
    "value": 14
}]
```

Although a far more jsonic structure would be:

```
{
    "cases": 23,
    "revenue": 34,
    "1D5": 56,
    "diag": 14
}
```

(posted as answer mainly for clarity)